# Python: Open a modules source code in Finder/Windows explorer

Tags: python, shell

Let's say I'm in the Python interactive shell, and I want to see the source code of a module I'm using.  Say, the `requests` module.  I know you can use `inspect.getsource()` to view the source code inside the command prompt.  But is there a python call that would open up that module's source directory in Finder or Windows Explorer?

Or is there a way to have `inspect.getsource()` open up the source code in an out-of-terminal editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question of 'But is there a python call that would open up that module's source directory in Finder or Windows Explorer?': you can use a subprocess to open your desired folder:

```
import subprocess
mydir="c:\\"
subprocess.Popen('explorer '+mydir)
```

To open the file in desired editor: If you know the path to your desired editor or if the desired editor is already in the windows path you can do something like:

```
import subprocess
myfile="c:\\"
myEditor="gvim" #assuming gvim is in the path. If not use the full path
subprocess.Popen(myEditor + ' ' +mydir)
```